# No upgrade to 17.10 notification yet

Tags: upgrade, 17.04, 17.10

Happily running Kubuntu 17.04.

I recently got an update notification and it updated a few packages.

However, there is no 'Upgrade to 17.10' notification yet.

Is this normal? Is the upgrade notification automatic or do I have to do something explicitly?

Comment: Have you run do-relase-upgrade?

Comment: Do I have to? Will I not get an upgrade notification like other update notifications?

Comment: It will definitely not hurt you. I guess you will get an upgrade notification. I did not wait to see. It also depends on the mirrors that you use.

Comment: @Bruni Yes, I agree. It will not hurt. But I thought it should be part of normal process of update/ upgrade. May be, I will wait a few more days and if nothing works, will issue do-release-upgrade at command prompt.